# multiple not mapped hidden input symfony2

Tags: symfony, twig, hidden-field

I have an article entity. When I create an article, I want to be able to add zero to n images to it.
To do so, I upload files with a jQuery plugin in a temporary directory, and add an `<input type=hidden>` to my form, with the file's full path as value.
It works fine when there is no validation error. But when there is, I got an error saying:

```
An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Notice: Array to string conversion") in form_div_layout.html.twig at line 13
```

And I'm pretty sure it's because it tries to do this :

```
ErrorHandler ->handleError ('8', 'Array to string conversion', '/var/www/project/app/cache/dev/twig/47/a4/ac9a00176739f843e919f5f89883191930038a6e0aaa218869e4966ab7c6.php', '175', array('context' => array('value' => array('njm4uqsa9y6@54edfdaedd0736w3wstk.jpeg'),...
```

Here is my formType :

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('title')
        ->add('content')
        ->add('maxVote')
        ->add('expireAt', 'datetime', array(
                'widget' => 'single_text',
                'input' => 'string',
                'format' => 'dd-mm-yyyy',
            )
        )
        ->add('category', 'entity', array(
                'class' => 'AppBundle:StoryCategory',
                'required' => true
            )
        )
        ->add('answers', 'collection', array(
                'type' => new AnswerType()
            )
        )
        ->add('visibility', 'choice', array(
                'choices'   => array(1 => "label.public", 2 => "label.semiprivate", 3 => "label.private"),
                'expanded' => false,
                'multiple' => false
            )
        )
        ->add('attachment', 'hidden', array(
                'mapped' => false,
                'required' => false
            )
        )
        ->add('save', 'submit')
    ;
}
```

Do you have any idea what is happening, or what should I do ?

Edit:

The form is empty. I create a new instance of Story

```
$story = new Story();
$form = $this->createForm(new StoryType(), $story);
```

And when I submit the form I do

```
$form->handleRequest($request);
```

Edit 2:
Story.php

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * Story
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="story")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\StoryRepository")
 */
class Story
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="string", length=255)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="content", type="text")
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    private $content;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="token", type="string", length=70, unique=true)
     */
    private $token;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="created_at", type="datetime")
     */
    private $createdAt;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="updated_at", type="datetime")
     */
    private $updatedAt;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="expire_at", type="datetime")
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    private $expireAt;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="author_ip", type="string", length=50, nullable=true)
     */
    private $authorIp;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="max_vote", type="integer", nullable=true)
     * @Assert\Type(type="integer")
     * @Assert\Range(
     *      min = 0,
     *      max = 20000,
     *      minMessage = "validation.story.maxvote.min",
     *      maxMessage = "validation.story.maxvote.max"
     * )
     */
    private $maxVote;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="nb_vote", type="integer")
     */
    private $nbVote;

    /**
     * @var integer
     * 1 = public, 2 = semi-private, 3 = private (only invited members)
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="visibility", type="integer")
     *
     */
    private $visibility;

    /**
     * @var boolean
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="is_active", type="boolean")
     */
    private $isActive;

    /**
    * @var StoryCategory
    *
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="StoryCategory", inversedBy="stories")
    * @ORM\JoinColumns({
    *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="id")
    * })
    * @Assert\NotNull()
    */
    private $category;

    /**
    * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Answer", mappedBy="story", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
    * @Assert\Count(
    *      min = "2",
    *      max = "4",
    *      minMessage = "validation.story.answer.min",
    *      maxMessage = "validation.story.answer.max",
    *      groups={"premium"}
    * )
    * @Assert\Count(
    *      min = "2",
    *      max = "2",
    *      minMessage = "validation.story.answer.min",
    *      maxMessage = "validation.story.answer.max",
    * )
    */
    private $answers;

    /**
    * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Attachment", mappedBy="story", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
    */
    private $attachments;

    /**
    * @var User
    *
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="stories")
    * @ORM\JoinColumns({
    *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
    * })
    */
    private $author;


    public function __construct()
    {
        $datetime = new \DateTime();
        $this->createdAt = $datetime;
        $this->updatedAt = $datetime;
        $this->token     = base_convert(time(), 10, 36).\AppBundle\Library\StringHelper::randomString();
        $this->isActive  = false;
        $this->nbVote    = 0;
    }
}
```

Twig view :

```
{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}

{% block basecontent %}
    {{ form_errors(form) }}
    {{ form_start(form, {attr: {id: 'story-form', novalidate: 'novalidate'}}) }}
    {{ form_row(form.title) }}
    {{ form_row(form.content) }}
    {{ form_row(form.category) }}
    <h3>Les choix de réponses possibles</h3>
    {% for answer in form.answers %}
        {{ form_widget(answer) }}
    {% endfor %}
    {{ form_row(form.visibility) }}
    {{ form_row(form.expireAt) }}
    {% for attachement in form.attachment %}
        {{ form_row(attachment) }}
    {% endfor %}
    {{ form_end(form) }}

    {# upload zone #}
    <div class="upload-block">
        <form action='{{ path('story_file_upload') }}' id="dropzone" class="dropzone">
        </form>
    </div>

{% endblock basecontent %}
```

This is what I add with javascript :

```
$("#story-form").append('<input type="hidden" name="story_form[attachment][]" value="'+response.filename+'"/>');
```

So I tried without it being an array (I removed the ending [] in the name), and it works. So I assume the problem comes from that, I have to tell the formType that it's an array. But how ?

Thank you

Comment: Can you show us how you're initializing your form (the data given to it)?

Comment: I edited the post on your demand

Comment: Thanks, can you please also give us the `Story` entity and the Twig view?

Comment: Here it is (I don't know if i need to comment for you to receive a notification when I edit the post)

Comment: Yes, you need :). Thank you.

Comment: I added the javascript part

Comment: In your `__construct` in `Story` entity, can you add: `$this->answers = new ArrayCollection();` ( do not forget to add the appropriate `use` statement) ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71802/discussion-between-hakim-and-alain-tiemblo).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't make it work, so I removed the "attachments" field from the formType.
When I upload a file, I then add using javascript an `<input type="hidden">` with a name that does not match the fields from the formType.
For example, the fields generated by Symfony are named `story_form['name']`. I just named mine `attachments[]`. That way Symfony doesn't tell me that there is an extra field.
In my controller I get the values with `$request->request->get('attachments')`.
There probably is a better way to do it, but I haven't found it.

Answer (score 0):

You're using in your vew:

```
{% for attachement in form.attachment %}
    {{ form_row(attachment) }}
{% endfor %}
```

Where your declaring `attachment` as an hidden field:

```
->add('attachment', 'hidden', array(
        'mapped' => false,
        'required' => false
    )
)
```

A hidden field is no more than a string stored in an `<input type="hidden">`, you can't iterate through it.